# Visual Studio 2008 Auto Save

Tags: visual-studio-2008, autosave

I just lost about an hour's of work when my computer crashed.  Is there a timed autosave feature in Visual Studio 2008?

If yes, where is it configured.

It's probably obvious, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: I must ask - what situation would you be in where you wouldn't save or test a source file for hours?

Comment: +1 IntelliJ IDEA has auto-save when you click out of the window or every X minutes.  Very helpful for some situations (a crash or power outage).  Auto-recover seems clunky in comparison.  With a VCS I don't see why VS shouldn't auto-save.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tools / Options / Environment / AutoRecover

?

Seems that the backup files are in this folder:

```
\...\My Documents\Visual Studio <version>\Backup Files\<projectname>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Found that, but took me a while to find the files themselves.  They are in: \...\My Documents\Visual Studio <version>\Backup Files\<projectname>.    Will you update your answer with this critical information so that I can accept it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's an add-in here: http://cbates.net/document-autosave-for-visual-studio/
it saves when focus is lost (very convenient).